# Problem after ati driver installation

Tags: linux, fedora, graphics, fglrx, ati

I've just installed the ati radeon drivers using the latest version on the ati site. Upon rebooting this has caused gnome 3 to fall back into a safe mode. My question boils down to how do I fix this mess? Is there a way to uninstall the ati drivers? Have I not completed the installation properly. Is there a better open source alternative?

I'm using fedora 15 and the drivers were catalyst 11.9. The graphics card is a HD 4570 on my laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I re-install the `fglrx64` RPM, which is every time the kernel is updated, I need to re-run `aticonfig --initial -v` manually. In fact, it's on a post-it on my server. I do it at runlevel 3, dunno if that matters. This is on CentOS, which should be the same.